# Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

I am trying to access my Geth node (specifically a smart contract at a particular address) running on a remote server from my UI (Angular JS)

It works perfectly when using **localhost** or the **ipv4** address on the same machine.

When trying to run the same code using the public IP address (ports are open), I am getting an error:

```
Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8585.
```

My code is as follow:

```
var Web3 = require('web3'); var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://x.x.x.x:8888'));
```

I have tried the following:

1) tried with local host or ipv4 at x.x.x.x
2) tried with 0.0.0.0 at x.x.x.x
3) public ip at x.x.x.x

My Geth command is:

```
geth  --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpc --rpcport "8585" --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --datadir="myChain" --port "30302"  --autodag --networkid 65535 --nat=none -
-rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3"  --nodiscover -verbosity 5 --maxpeers 3
console
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have opened up your node on port `8585` yet are attempting to connect on port `8888`.

Your code should be:

```
var Web3 = require('web3'); 
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://x.x.x.x:8585'));
```

Also, you are running your node with loads of parameters. Do you know what they all do?

I would suggest reading the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options).

```
geth --fast --rpc --rpccorsdomain="https://TheDomainYouAreAccessingTheNodeFrom.com" --rpcaddr=TheIPOfTheNode --rpcapi eth,web3
```

Comment: hi thomas thanks for suggestion ,tried by changing the port make it same in my web3 and in geth command but still getting same error...!! what else i need to do ?

Comment: One question ..in web3 set providers what i need to put ip of the node,domain,localhost or 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: The IP that the node is running on, or a domain pointing to that IP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble and spend a lot of time to find the reason.
web3.js has XMLHttpRequest (npm module) as a dependency. This module writes some temp files when sending a request.
(see here:  [xmlhttprequest source](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/master/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js), line 477 )

**It means your NodeJs process needs to write files permission**

Comment: How to give that permission?  I am running a node.js script using "node file.js" so how to give that permission?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a CORS issues.
I tried to Turn off CORS. For example:

1.[how to turn off cors in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

2. [Use a plugin for your browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)
3. Use a proxy such as nginx. [example of how to set up](http://oskarhane.com/avoid-cors-with-nginx-proxy_pass/)

It actually worked. For development is fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your internet connection to other one or restart it.
That's was my problem.